# Ciclo for de Javascript se cuelga y congela el navegador sin hacer absolutamente nada

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo este código al cual intento hacerlo funcionar... supuestamente el resultado esperado sería 0, 2, 4 pero resulta ser que al ejecutarlo no hace absolutamente nada y de hecho se cuelga el navegador... he intentado varias veces tanto con Visual Studio Code como con IDES online (JSFiddle, JSBin, Codepen, etc) y el comportamiento ha sido el mismo y de hecho lo compartí con otra persona y le pasó exactamente igual... ¿alguien sabrá el por qué?

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i+2) {
  document.write(i + "<br>"); 
}
```

Comment: Si le haces un console log veras que todo el rato da 0

Comment: A riesgo de sonar pedante, este ciclo infinito pudo haber sido evitado sólo mirando a la sintaxis del `for`. Después que se colgara el navegador, lo primero que hay que hacer es revisar las fronteras del ciclo: Desde donde inicia, hasta dónde va, cómo se actualiza. Voté negativamente la pregunta porque se resolvía con **leer el código atentamente** e **investigar**. OP no hizo ninguna de las dos. Si alguien está en desacuerdo, estoy dispuesto a cambiar de opinión.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El navegador se cuelga porque entra en un bucle infinito.

Si te fijas, en la sección de incremento del `for` estás sumando `i + 2` pero no asignas nada a `i` por lo que permanece igual y nunca sale del ciclo.

Suponiendo que querías que `i` aumente de a 2, la solución sería `i = i + 2` o `i += 2` si prefieres usar el operador de suma- asignación.

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i += 2) {
    document.write(i + "<br>"); 
}
```

Comment: Amigo donde puedo ver como poner mi codigo y que se puede ejecutar ?

Comment: @MateoGuio Cuando estés editando o creando una respuesta, pulsa Ctrl + M para insertar un fragmento ejecutable

Comment: Muchas gracias Bro

Comment: Y solo funciona con HTML, CSS y Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo tu error esta en el ciclo, para incrementar en 2 la variable "i" en cada iteracion la manera correcta seria esta:

```html
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i += 2) {
    document.write(i + "<br>"); 
}
```